# XML parsing errors with Xamarin Forms with Grial UI Kit

Tags: android, xml, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms, t4

So I am using Grial UI Kit with my Xamarin Forms App. I am following the instructions [mentioned here](https://github.com/UXDivers/Grial-UI-Kit-Support/wiki/Adding-Grial-on-existing-project:-Setting-up-Grial-theme-required-files) for both iOS & Android. It works pretty well for iOS. For Android however it throws an error on Line 2 of the Colors.tt file.

The Colors.tt file has the below code:

```
<#@ template language="C#" hostspecific="True" #>
<#@ output extension=".xml" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Drawing" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Xml" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Xml" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Drawing" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Globalization" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Windows" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Windows" #>
<# 
string path = Host.ResolvePath("../../../PCLFolderName/App.xaml");
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(path);

Dictionary<string, Color> knownColors = new Dictionary<string, Color> ();
List<string> exports = new List<string> ();

XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("artina", "clr-namespace:UXDivers.Artina.Shared;assembly=UXDivers.Artina.Shared");
nsmgr.AddNamespace ("xamarin", "http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms");

XmlNode resources = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/xamarin:Application/xamarin:Application.Resources/xamarin:ResourceDictionary", nsmgr);

if (resources != null) {
    foreach (XmlNode node in resources.ChildNodes) {
        if (node.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Comment) {
            var comment = node.InnerText.Trim (); 

            Match match = Regex.Match(comment, @"Export\s([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            if (match.Success)
            {
                exports.Add (match.Groups[1].Value);
            }
        }
        else if (node.Name == "Color") {
            string colorName = null;

            foreach (XmlAttribute attribute in node.Attributes) {
                if (attribute.LocalName == "Key") {
                    colorName = attribute.Value;
                    var colorDefinition = node.InnerText.Trim ();
                    Color color;

                    if (colorDefinition.StartsWith ("#")) {
                        if (colorDefinition.Length == 7) {
                            colorDefinition = "FF" + colorDefinition;
                        }

                        int argb = Int32.Parse (colorDefinition.Replace ("#", ""), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
                        color = Color.FromArgb (argb);
                    } else {
                        color = Color.FromName (colorDefinition);
                        string colorString = string.Format("#FF{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}",
                        color.R, color.G, color.B);

                        color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(colorString);
                    }

                    knownColors.Add (colorName, color);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}               
if (exports.Count > 0){
#>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
    <!-- Artina Exported Colors -->
<#
  foreach(var name in exports){ 
     Color color;

     if (knownColors.TryGetValue(name, out color)){
#>
    <color name="<#= name #>">#<#= color.A.ToString("X2") #><#= color.R.ToString("X2") #><#= color.G.ToString("X2") #><#= color.B.ToString("X2") #></color>
<#
     }
  }
#>
</resources>
<#
}
#>
```

The error is thrown on line# 2:
    <#@ output extension=".xml" #>

The error message is:

**Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)**

Has anybody faced this before? Any solutions or comments are greatly appreciated.

Thanks.
Noel

PS:

1. Development is done using VS2015 + Xamarin VS + Windows 10 on a Mac.
2. All SDK's have been updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was resolved by changing the build action on the colors.tt file to None.